# Phonegap FileTransfer crashes when downloading large files

Tags: cordova

I'm using PhoneGap's FileTransfer object to download large files
for offline use.
Smaller files of 5Mb or so download just fine, however larger files
are crashing the app with "Out of Memory" errors. Has anyone had any
luck with downloading large files? Is there a plugin available that
can fix this?

Comment: do you test on emulator or device

Comment: no, but I tested it over 2 device which have android version 2.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add `android:largeHeap="true"` to your application's manifest file, clean the project and try

```
<application 
    android:largeHeap="true"
    ...
    ...
```

Comment: Is there also a solution for iOS?

Comment: how do you do that in Cordova? The ApplicationManifest.xml is auto-generated

Comment: @sritmak you do have access to manifest.xml in any Android project. My answer was for a question asked a year ago. But it will still work!

Comment: I'm in a Visual Studio Cordova project, the build is automatic, I was looking for that answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/28981471/1835270 for where to write your solution